# Proof of a lemma.

Tags: real-numbers, ordered-fields

In my textbook, the author offers a proof for the density of the rationals within the reals (where the reals are a ordered Archmediean field with completeness), and proves that they're everywhere dense by saying that for $0 \leq a \leq b$ (for real $a$ & $b$) there is a positive integer $n$ such that ${1\over n } \leq b-a$ and also that $a < m({1 \over n})$ for a positive integer $m$. Then, the author says that we assume that there exists a $k \over n$ ($k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$) which is the least that can satisfy $a < m({1 \over n})$. The rest is irrelevant to my question but the proof hinges on this "least ${k \over n}$" where by $a < {k \over n}$ and ${{k-1} \over n} \leq a < {k \over n}$, but I've no idea if it exists or not (in terms of proof). Does someone know how to prove it?

Comment: The set $\{k \geq 0 : a < \frac{k}{n}\}$ is a nonempty subset of the nonnegative integers. As such, it has a least element by the well-ordering principle. Clearly we must have $k \geq 1$ since $a \geq 0$. As $k-1$ is a smaller nonnegative integer than $k$, it does not lie in that set, so it is not the case that $a < \frac{k-1}{n}$, that is, it must be that $\frac{k-1}{m} \leq a$.

Comment: @jl00 I'm more so asking for the set $\{r \in \mathbb{Q} : a < r\}$ not for $k$... if we assume that there is a least $a < r$ or there isn't a least $a < r$, by the well-ordering theorem, there will still be a least element as any subset of the integers is well-ordered. (I.e. if the set has the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ or less than it, it still won't matter as in both cases [ending or never ending] there will be a least element.)

Comment: The rationals are not well-ordered so it is not obvious to me that it will have a least element for that subset.

Comment: Sorry I don't exactly understand your reply. The set $\{r \in \mathbb{Q} : a < r\}$ does not have a least element (unless you mean nonnegative rationals, in which case it is still unlikely to have a minimum). But the set $\{ k \in \mathbb{Z} :  k \geq 0 \text{ and } a < \frac{k}{n}\}$ is clearly a subset of the nonnegative integers which is a well-ordered set and therefore this nonempty subset of them has a least element.

Comment: @jl00 I think I get your point now, your edit of the set made it more clear now.

Comment: Yea sorry about that I tried to edit my first comment to make it more clear but the 5 minute time mark had expired. I hope everything is clear now!

Comment: It's fine, I just got it backwards as I thought of the infinite number of possible elements in both the positive and negative direction (if we assumed there is no least) but the author of the book shows that you don't need to prove it for the negatives if you can prove it for the positives, and your edit of $k \geq 0$ reminded me of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be restated as: For each real number $b$ and each natural number $n$, there is a unique integer $m$ such that $m/n$ is in the interval $[b – 1/n, b)$.

For such an $m/n$, we would have $b – 1/n \leq m/n < b$, or $nb - 1 ≤ m < nb$.

Comment: Why the "a unique part"?

Comment: @Math3147 So that one can write, for any real number $c  = nb -1$ above, there is exactly one integer $m$ in $[c, c +1)$.